# Comparison between data in 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sets of data in 2 columns and want to spot the error in the data as the below example: the error here in the highlighted in yellow.

I have tried with script dictionary but still can't spot the error. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Should be doable using `IF` and  `COUNTIFS`.

Comment: What is the logic for identifying an error? Is it: "If most of the records for the same customer are value some value and you find rows or multiple rows with something besides "some value" then flag it?"

Comment: "I have tried with script dictionary"  -always helps to post the code you tried...

Comment: Hi JNevill, I was looking for a loop to identify that if all the types that under the same account number are the same and if one is different then that's an error. like the type XO with account 566882.

Comment: You need to explain the logic in more detail. What should happen if there are only 2 different values? What if there are 3 values and the first is different than the other 2? What if there are 4 and there are 3 different values? Add the clarifications and the code you have tried to your post.

Comment: The logic is that if there's a different type to the rest of the types under the same account then just highlight it in yellow. it does not need to delete or anything else. so what is the best approach for such a scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Highlight Rows

[image]

```vb
Sub HighlightRows()

    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet
        With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("E:G"))
            rCount = .Rows.Count - 1
            Set rg = .Resize(rCount).Offset(1)
        End With
    End With
    
    Dim uData(): uData = rg.Columns(1).Value
    Dim vData(): vData = rg.Columns(3).Value
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim urg As Range, r As Long, uStr As String
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        uStr = CStr(uData(r, 1))
        If dict.Exists(uStr) Then
            If StrComp(CStr(vData(r, 1)), dict(uStr), vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                If urg Is Nothing Then
                    Set urg = rg.Rows(r)
                Else
                    Set urg = Union(urg, rg.Rows(r))
                End If
            End If
        Else
            dict(uStr) = CStr(vData(r, 1))
        End If
    Next r
    
    If Not urg Is Nothing Then
        rg.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        urg.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
       
End Sub
```